# AppEngine: loading templates from a static directory (not just '/')

Tags: django, google-app-engine, templates

I'm trying to make `template.render()` (import was: `from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template`) use a template located in a directory other than the root of the application.

I have a directory, called `static`, where I'd like to keep my templates. Or possibly, I'll change that to `static/templates` later, but this doesn't matter.

The problem? `TemplateDoesNotExist: index.html`, a sad exception.

This:

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
logging.debug(path)
self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

.. works, but this:

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static/index.html')
logging.debug(path)
self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

.. does not.

`/static` has been added to `app.yaml`, although it shouldn't matter.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `/static` to `app.yaml` *does* cause files in `/static` to be treated differently.

See http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Static_File_Handlers and note:

> If you have data files that need to be read by the application code, the data files must be application files, and must not be matched by a static file pattern.

Templates are data files.